# Using keylset in TCL to return multiple values in a row on parsing

Tags: parsing, tcl

I have an output

```
Application
----------------------------------------
ID 5 - Value 1
ID 5 - Value 2
ID 6 -  Value 1
ID 6 - Value 2
----------------------------------------
```

I am parsing it using keylset in tcl
Right now, what I am getting after parsing is:

```
ID
    5
        Value
             1 = 1
             2 = 2
    6
        Value
             1 = 1
             2 = 2
```

Can any one please suggest me how I can get it in following way.

```
  ID
    5
        Value 1,2
    6 
        Value 1,2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `keylget`'s optional retval argument when retrieving before `lappend` and `keylset` to put it back, perhaps like this:

```
set seq {}
keylget data ID.$id.Value seq
lappend seq $theValue
keylset data ID.$id.Value $seq
```